# How to achieve this layout with Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm at a complete loss as to how to create this layout:

[image]

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final _username, _email, _password;

  @override
  _SignupScreenState createState() => new _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Email'
                )
              ),
              new TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password'
                )
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: new Text('Sign In')
              ),
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: new Text('Sign Up')
              ),
            ],
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The result:

[image]

How do I get that `FlatButton` at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I recommend you have a look at https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/

Comment: @Edman You're not the first to point me to that tutorial, which I've looked at of course... I'm still very very confused. I don't know if it's my HTML and CSS brain that's doing this to me. I often work with flexbox in web dev but it seems that this only has a very few similarities and thinking layout in Flutter is just flexbox can hurt you... which it is... a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: new HomePage(),
      ),
    );

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextField(
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Username'),
                  ),
                  new TextField(
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: new RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: new Text('Login'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: new Text('Register'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'll of course accept the answer because it achieves the desired result. But I sure hope that one day we'll look back and think "Boy! Layout in Flutter Beta sure sucked major ****** ! Thank goodness they fixed that!" .... The amount of code needed to do this is laughable.

Comment: Yep. That's a lot of code just for the UI part but at the same time you will have apps for both Android and IOS without any performance issues.

Comment: You're right, I need to remember that. Makes it more bearable. :)

Comment: you can use the Stack widget as well to do the same with your flat button wrapped in an Align with alignment bottoncenter

Comment: Stack widget is for a different purpose. i.e for stacking child widgets above each other not for positioning widgets.

Comment: Actually in this solution the text fields aren't really centered on the screen, they're offset by the height of the button on the bottom. Not necessarily a problem, but that's something that would be fixed with e.g. a stack.

Comment: I wish the Flutter developers team, can understand, that building even a simple UI is worse than working with HTML about 20yrs ago. They have such a great product but how can they not consider making UI as easy or logical like a Constraint Layout in Android?